# Cannot Update Git Submodule

Tags: git

I am currently trying to clone some of my vim settings from my git repo, and the repo mostly contains submodules of other hosted projects. However, when I try to update all of my submodules, I get the following error.

```
Cloning into bundle/ack...
remote: Counting objects: 318, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (189/189), done.
remote: Total 318 (delta 124), reused 256 (delta 70)
Receiving objects: 100% (318/318), 48.13 KiB, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (124/124), done.
Submodule path 'bundle/ack': checked out 'fd9632b40ac07b39adb270311cde2c460c9ba6da'
Cloning into bundle/command-t...
remote: Counting objects: 2820, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1434/1434), done.
remote: Total 2820 (delta 1348), reused 2574 (delta 1122)
Receiving objects: 100% (2820/2820), 2.75 MiB | 701 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1348/1348), done.
Submodule path 'bundle/command-t': checked out '07087e16ba8fe0a87b1d1ccd03e158a0157dc1f8'
Cloning into bundle/fugitive...
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 400
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git' into submodule path 'bundle/fugitive' failed
```

I cannot then update the rest of my plugins. I am accessing github over ssh (rather than HTTPS). Also, is there a way I can update the rest of my plugins (submodules) individually?

Comment: Check to make sure the path to the submodule is correct - you're getting an HTTP/400 error which means the request is formatted incorrectly. I would posit that the path might be slightly off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can reproduce the issue: does this work?

```
 git clone http://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive.git
```

(I just tested it, and it clones just fine)

It is possible it was a glitch due to some [recent GitHub availability issue](https://status.github.com/messages):

> 14:22 UTC A small percentage of git repositories are currently unavailable due to emergency maintenance on one of our fileserver pairs.

Second, your url isn't using https: you can try and switch the url with:

```
https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive
or
git@github.com:tpope/vim-fugitive.git
```

For that, with git 1.8.3+, you need to:

```
git submodule deinit bundle/fugitive
# edit .gitmodules
git submodule update --init bundle/fugitive
```

Comment: For what it's worth for future reads of this post - we had a very similar issue where the difference between `ssh` and `https` calls was exactly the issue only we needed to edit two files for each submodule - edit the repository's path in `.gitmodule` and edit the repository's path in `.git/config`